# Mutex behaviour under Linux

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm trying to control access via a multi-process console application, so that only one process can run a specific part of the code at a time.

Actually, I would have liked to use a mutex for this, but the Mutex class doesn't seem to work on Linux.

My code:

```
using var mutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\TestMutex");
if (mutex.WaitOne(0, false)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Mutex erhalten");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Mutex nicht erhalten");
}
Console.WriteLine("Beliebige Taste drücken zum beenden.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Working on Windows:

[image: Result on Windows]

Not working on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04/NET6):

[image: Result on Linux]

Am I missing something?

---

My current workaround ist to have a "Lockfile" but I didn't want to maintain an additional utility class.

utility class:

```
public class LockfileMutex : IDisposable {
    private readonly string _fileName;

    private FileStream? _stream;

    public LockfileMutex(string name) {
        var assemblyDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(LockfileMutex).Assembly.Location) ?? throw new FileNotFoundException("cannot determine assembly location");
        var file = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(assemblyDir, name));
        _fileName = file;
    }

    public bool Acquire() {
        try {
            _stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains(_fileName)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (_stream != null) {
            _stream.Dispose();

            try {
                File.Delete(_fileName);
            } catch {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
using (var mutex = new LockfileMutex("MyMutex")) {
    if (mutex.Acquire()) {
        Console.WriteLine("acquired");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("not acquired");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("press any key to end");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Here's a thread, since the mutex is implemented by either shm or lockfile, you can check if 2 processes open the same file. The shm file will be created in `/tmp/.dotnet/shm/global/`, the lockfile will be created in `/tmp/.dotnet/lockfiles/global/`